# How to insert base64string to varbinary type column sql sever

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have base64string (image logo), which I want to insert in db. In database the column type is varbinary. my query is

```
update Organization set MobileLogo='gjdgfkjgk...' where orgId=1676
```

The below error I am getting

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 Implicit conversion from data type
>   varchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT
>   function to run this query.

Code to convert image to base64

```
string imagePath = @"C:\Users\arvind.ch\Downloads\Icons\SISClient_iCons\Enrich.png";
string imgBase64String = GetBase64StringForImage(imagePath);
```

Here I want to store the image-

[image]

I need to have sql query to inset it to db not C# code. The URL's given above is all about C#

Comment: base 64 is a way of taking *arbitrary binary data* and making it storable/transmittable as a string. And you have a `varbinary` column which is capable of storing *arbitrary binary data*. Do you maybe think you're missing the obvious here?

Comment: Don't convert to base 64 / *decode* the base 64 to get back to arbitrary binary data. Then pass that to SQL Server directly in a `varbinary` parameter and *avoid* treating it as a string at all. It's most natural representation is binary data. *store that*.

Comment: Post the actual code that stores the image. Not the code that converts it to a string.

Answer (score 2):

Two things are needed to answer this properly:

First, let's answer your question about how to store the object. You've already made a varbinary column, so don't bother with the Base64 conversion, as a varbinary column can store arbitrary data already. Read the file into a byte array and then send that to the database.

Second, and probably what is making this seem difficult to do, is that you need to parameterize your SQL. This is for two reasons: 1) To allow you to send the byte array in the first place and 2) To prevent SQL injection attacks, which are the easiest vulnerabilities to defend against.

Consider the following code, which will do both:

```
using ( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection ("your connection string"))
using ( SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Organization SET MobileLogo=@FileData WHERE YourKeyColumn=@YourKeyValue", con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure } )
{
    con.Open();
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileData", yourByteArray);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YourKeyValue", yourKeyValue);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: @dodexahedron- Thank u. But I am using Sql-server to insert image to db. Using C# to convert image to base64.

Comment: @Arvindraja *don't* use C# to convert the binary data to a string. `varbinary(max)` is a *binary* type. Base64 is a *string*. Store the binary data in the varbinary(max) field

Comment: Yeah! now trying to convert image to binary.

Comment: @Arvindraja why convert anything? Just load the image file. Perhaps you should clarify your question and post the actual code you are using?

Comment: The image is *already* binary. Don't convert it to a string. Just read the file into a byte array and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server told you everything:

> Use the [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to run this query.

Here is udated query:

```
update Organization set MobileLogo=convert(varbinary(MAX),'gjdgfkjgk...') where orgId=1676
```

You could also convert values on client side using `Convert.FromBase64String`:

```
var varbinaryData = Convert.FromBase64String("gjdgfk45vbgu");
```

**UPDATE** after question update:

To read file as byte array, use:

```
var imagePath = @"C:\Users\arvind.ch\Downloads\Icons\SISClient_iCons\Enrich.png";
var byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
```

Then pass this `byteArray` as query parameter.

Comment: When I am doing this, getting error- Msg 9002, Level 17, State 2, Line 1
The transaction log for database 'TestDb' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/troubleshoot-a-full-transaction-log-sql-server-error-9002?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Convert.FromBase64String("gjdgfk45vbgu"), this line giving me array of binary like 03 56 66 77... how can I collect it?